# How do I store static data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

In our application we will give titles to users based on their points. So, if a user has 10-99 points, that user might get the "Novice" title, but a user with 100-199 points might get the "Regular User" title. I plan on eager loading a user's points using an attribute and relationship, and once I have those points I will use an attribute method to assign the title.

But how do I get the list of possible titles?

I could make a model, a migration, and a seed file, but I feel like these titles won't change much and certainly would never need to be updated in an API call. I could also hardcode an array of points and titles and do a quick lookup to see which title belongs to a user, but then I need to somehow deliver those titles to the user in an Attribute method. Or I could store them in a repository or the cache.

Can I access a repository from within a model? Is it better to store this sort of data in a DB anyways, regardless of how often it's updated or queried?

Answer (score 0):

You could use entries in your `.env` file to store the entries and then use some logic in your php to select the correct `.env` entry.

```
LEVEL_1_TITLE=Novice
LEVEL_2_TITLE=Regular
...

if($user->points < 99){
    $title = env('LEVEL_1_TITLE');
}
...
```

Or do the same thing from an `array` in a class that you create and just select the correct array entry based on the points.